# could someone merge my accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Before registering, I answered a few questions via https://math.stackexchange.com/users/41865/julien-s-r 
Would it be possible to have that account merged with my current one?

Answer (score 2):

Done. In the future, you don't need to write meta posts for things like merging; you can just flag a moderator.